# Android - How to avoid a fragment be recreated when press back button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use an unique activity that contain navigation view and their option will open another fragment. Everything is ok, unless the MainFragment is being recreated when back from another fragment (that was opened from the navigation view). I'd like to know how to avoid this because it's loading the list again.

MainActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.home);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.layout, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
   }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_home).setChecked(true);
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_history:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.layout, new Fragment2())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                break;
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Main Fragment:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.example.adapters.ScheduledServicesAdapter;
import br.com.example.entities.ScheduledService;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    private final class ScheduleServiceTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ScheduledService>> {

        @Override
        protected List<ScheduledService> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            mList = new ArrayList<>();
            mList.add(new ScheduledService(new Date(), 250.50, 0));
            mList.add(new ScheduledService(new Date(), 50.75, 0));

            return mList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<ScheduledService> scheduledServices) {
            super.onPostExecute(scheduledServices);
            setData(scheduledServices);
        }
    }

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ScheduledServicesAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<ScheduledService> mList;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(),
            linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

        new ScheduleServiceTask().execute();
    }

    private void setData(List<ScheduledService> list) {
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter = new ScheduledServicesAdapter(list);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            TextView emptyText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.empty_text);
            emptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment 2 has a hello world text view for test purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When you put your `MainFragment` to `BackStack` (means that the view
   of this `fragment` is not `visible` because `Fragment2` take the
   screen), all the views which belong to it will be destroyed.
2. Then when you back to MainFragment from another fragment, view of
   MainFragment will be re-created. That mean `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated` will be
   called again.
3. In your case, I suggest:

   - Move `new ScheduleServiceTask().execute();` to `onCreate` or to
     another method (example: `requestGetData()`)
   - Init `mAdapter` and set `adapter` for `mRecyclerView` in `onViewCreated()`
   - On `setData()` method, all you need is re-set data for `mAdapter` and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Even the fragment be recreated, mList variable isn't null and the whole data is there. I've cheked mList != null before call new ScheduledTask().execute. This way I avoid querying again.

Answer (score 0):

@Douglas Fomaro, Better you can move your data(mList) outside fragment. Maintain DataManager Class that hold all your list data value.